# Почему не заполняются значения?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;

namespace Prakt5
{
class ThreeAngle
{
    public double firstside;
    public double secondside;
    public double thirdside;



    public void PrintValue()
    {
        ThreeAngle threeAngle = new ThreeAngle();

        Console.Write("Введите первую сторону треугольника: ");
        threeAngle.firstside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите вторую сторону треугольника: ");
        threeAngle.secondside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите третью сторону треугольника: ");
        threeAngle.thirdside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void PrintLine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Стороны треугольника: {firstside}, {secondside}, {thirdside}");
    }

    public void Print_P_and_S(double firstside, double secondside, double thirdside)
    {
        double p = firstside + secondside + thirdside;

        double area = Math.Sqrt(p * (p - firstside) * (p - secondside) * (p - thirdside));

        Console.WriteLine($"Периметр треугольника: {p}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Площадь треугольника: {area}");
    }

}


class Program
{




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ThreeAngle threeAngle = new ThreeAngle();

        threeAngle.PrintValue();
        threeAngle.PrintLine();
        threeAngle.Print_P_and_S(threeAngle.firstside, threeAngle.secondside, threeAngle.thirdside);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что локальная переменная `threeAngle`, чьим полям Вы присваиваете значения, благополучно уйдет в небытие, как только метод `PrintValue` отработает.

```
public void PrintValue()
{
    //ThreeAngle threeAngle = new ThreeAngle();

    Console.Write("Введите первую сторону треугольника: ");
    firstside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Введите вторую сторону треугольника: ");
    secondside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Введите третью сторону треугольника: ");
    thirdside = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```